# Variable initailization after being called is reflected beforehand

Tags: c, initialization

I am learning about scoping of variable in C.
Can anyone please explain what is going on below?

```
  int w;
  printf("\nw=%d\n", w);     
  w =-1;
```

Despite the fact that I initialized variable 'w' after 'printf', it always gets the value of "-1". This confused me, as I expect it to run sequentially. Hence, it should have printed some random value.
*** I also tried changing the value there, and it always read the written value. Hence, it did not randomly show "-1"

For experiment, I again tried the code below.

```
  int w;
  printf("\nw=%d\n", w);     
  w =-9;
  w =-1;
```

Now, it reads a value of "2560". As I expect since it was not properly initialized before.

Comment: How is -1 wrong? -1 is no less a random value than 2560

Comment: undefined behaviour at your service; learn more about that notion if you want to write in C

Comment: You shouldn't expect anything from an incorrect program. Undefined behavior means that literally anything (including seemingly doing the right thing) can happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is optimizing the assignment of w in the first case. In the second case, it is deciding not to optimize.

In both cases, the compiler *could* choose to optimize out both assignments, since w is not used after they appear.

Initialize your variables before using them.

Comment: What does the presence or absence of the assignment statements following the `printf` have to do with the undefined behavior of reading an uninitialized variable (other than possibly affecting the value stored in whatever memory location `w` refers to the next time the program runs)?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out about the compiler optimizing. It helped me find out that my autocompile add "-O2" flag in the command line. And after I remove it out, the result is as one expects => the result shows "0"

Answer (score 7):

In your code

```
int w;
printf("\nw=%d\n", w);
```

invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you're trying to read the value of an uninitialized (automatic local) variable. The content of `w` is indeterminate at this point, and the output result is, well, undefined.

Always initialize your local variable before *reading* (using) the value.

---

Related: Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.9, *Initialization*

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate. [....]

and, related to *Undefined behavior*, annex §J.2

> The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is
>   indeterminate

Comment: In the spec, it seems to talk about an *indeterminate value*, not necessarily full UB. Of course, reading an indeterminate value can have results that are as hazardous as those of UB, but it still uses different terminology. Could you cite the spec on this?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis There you go. Hope that be enough. :)

Comment: Oh, I might have missed the second snippet the last time I read that part of the spec. It makes sense that this is UB, then. Thanks for taking the time to find it. =)

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Pleasure is mine. :)

Answer (score 4):

The variable in uninitialized.  In "C", this means its value is "nondeterministic".  In reality, the variable generally gets a value based on what's "laying around" at the memory address to which it gets assigned.  In this case, its some value left on the stack.

It just so happens that often you will get consistent results across multiple runs simply due to external factors on which a program should not rely.

Answer (score 1):

In both the above cases

```
  int w;
  printf("\nw=%d\n", w);
```

returns a random garbage value as we might call it which could be anything including `-1` or `2560`.

Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

When you do not initialize a variable it can contain garbage value. Hence it's undefined behaviour and in most cases it will print random numbers as you experienced. By the way, as pointed out by others it's up to the compiler, so it may work with the expected value or it may don't work.